# Is it possible to send mails by bash script via smtp?

Tags: bash, smtp, postfix-mta

I have postfix+dovecot.  I want to make bash script which can use SMTP for this. I don't want use sendmail.

Is it possible?  May be someone has some examples of code?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a SMTP client?

Comment: What's wrong with postfix' `sendmail` wrapper?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server might answer your question . Ssmtp.

Answer (score 27):

Boy, when that gauntlet is thrown, it always `bash`es me right upside the head!  :-)

```
#!/bin/sh

function checkStatus {
  expect=250
  if [ $# -eq 3 ] ; then
    expect="${3}"
  fi
  if [ $1 -ne $expect ] ; then
    echo "Error: ${2}"
    exit
  fi
}

MyHost=`hostname`

read -p "Enter your mail host: " MailHost
MailPort=25

read -p "From: " FromAddr

read -p "To: " ToAddr

read -p "Subject: " Subject

read -p "Message: " Message

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${MailHost}/${MailPort}

read -u 3 sts line
checkStatus "${sts}" "${line}" 220

echo "HELO ${MyHost}" >&3

read -u 3 sts line
checkStatus "$sts" "$line"

echo "MAIL FROM: ${FromAddr}" >&3

read -u 3 sts line
checkStatus "$sts" "$line"

echo "RCPT TO: ${ToAddr}" >&3

read -u 3 sts line
checkStatus "$sts" "$line"

echo "DATA" >&3

read -u 3 sts line
checkStatus "$sts" "$line" 354

echo "Subject: ${Subject}" >&3
echo "${Message}" >&3
echo "." >&3

read -u 3 sts line
checkStatus "$sts" "$line"
```

Comment: This seems that I look for. Thanks.

Comment: glad I could demonstrate this for you!

Comment: the to in the mail client is empty with this

Answer (score 17):

Have just found this tiny but wonderful utility `sendemail` (not `sendmail`). The syntax is too simple to explain.

Example:

```
SERVER="smtp.company.com"
FROM="sender@company.com"
TO="recepient@company.com"
SUBJ="Some subject"
MESSAGE="Some message"
CHARSET="utf-8"

sendemail -f $FROM -t $TO -u $SUBJ -s $SERVER -m $MESSAGE -v -o message-charset=$CHARSET
```

More info available through help or at the author's site: 
https://github.com/mogaal/sendemail.

Answer (score 9):

Tested with gmail and it currently works.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Use "host -t mx yourispdomain" to find out yourispmailserver
exec 1<>/dev/tcp/yourispmailserver/25
a=$(cat <<"MAILEND"
HELO local.domain.name
MAIL FROM: <me@local.domain.name>
RCPT TO: <you@local.domain.name>
DATA
From: me@local.domain.name
To: you@local.domain.name
Subject: test
send your orders for pizza to the administrator.
.
QUIT
.
MAILEND
)
IFS='
'
declare -a b=($a)
for x in "${b[@]}"
 do
   echo $x
   sleep 1
 done
```

Answer (score 3):

- Install sSMTP, for instance:

  `apt-get install ssmtp`
- Configure ssmtp:

  `sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

  · Server: `mailhub=smtp.1und1.de:587`

  · Hostname: `hostname=subdomain.domain.com`

  · User: `AuthUser=user@domain.com`

  · Pass: `AuthPass=your_password`

Then in your sh file, do what you need and pipe it to mail, for instance:

`#!/bin/bash
du -sh | mail -s "Disk usage report" user@domain.com`

OR

`#!/bin/bash
echo "Today's DB backup is ok." | mail -s "DB daily backup alert" user@domain.com`

Comment: Getting error: `sSMTP[19315]: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me when you say that you don't want to use sendmail. May be you don't want to use the sendmail process.

Postfix has an executable called "sendmail", and may be you could want to use it because I cannot think why you should not.

```
#/bin/bash

FROM='from@test.com'
TO='to@test.com'
SUBJECT='This is a test message'

BODY="This is a test mail message body.
Hi there.
"

printf "From: <%s>\nTo: <%s>\nSubject: %s\n\n%s" "$FROM" "$TO" "$SUBJECT" "$BODY" | sendmail -f "$FROM"
```

Comment: I agree, may be I'm not say clear. I mean, that I want to know about possibility of bash script to use smtp auth to connect to remote smtp server and send mail.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SSMTP. Maybe this one helps too:

http://tecadmin.net/send-email-smtp-server-linux-command-line-ssmtp/

Comment: SSMTP allowed to send emails via SMTP server as well.  There are anohter option to use sendEmail command.

https://tecadmin.net/send-email-from-gmail-smtp-via-linux-command/

or 

https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/

Answer (score 1):

Also wanted to throw in another solution here, useful if you don't have access to sendmail etc. Most linux servers will have telnet, so we can use that.

```
function send_email{

echo "EHLO my_mail_server.example.com"   # replace this with your mail server domain
sleep 1
echo "MAIL FROM: my_from_address@example.com
sleep 1
echo "RCPT TO: my_to_address@example.com
sleep 1
echo "DATA
sleep 1
echo "Subject: My Subject Line"
sleep 1
echo "To: my_to_address@example.com"
sleep 1
echo "From: my_from_address@example.com"
sleep 1
echo "This is the body of my email. Put whatever in here."
sleep 1
echo "." # signifies the end of data entry, mail will be queued to send.
}

send_email | telnet 1.2.3.4 25 # call the function and pass it into telnet command.
```

Comment: I am going to use this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want `bash` to talk directly to an SMTP server?  That's not really going to happen.  It might *technically* be possible using the support for network communication available in bash, but realistically you don't want to go down that path.

That means that what you really need is to call an external program that will take of SMTP for you.  Typically, that's going to be `sendmail`, but if you're trying to avoid that there are lots of other alternatives, including:

- [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/)
- Heirloom [mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html)

Both of these can handle communication with a remote SMTP server without involving sendmail.

Comment: people often do because sendmail, msmtp. postfix etc may not be installed *and configured*

Answer (score 0):

**I love dldnh's answer!**

Perfect solution for sending administrative alerts via your dedicated smtp relay (I know you've got one).  No sense putting smtp/Postfix/etc on more than one server, right?

I do have one suggestion: Send one blank line before your message text to let the relay know that no more headers are coming.  Without the blank line, the text of your message may not be sent; for example if there is a colon in that first line of the message.

Here is a small rewrite I took liberties with:

```
#!/bin/bash
MyHost=$(hostname)
MailHost="mail"
MailPort=25

function checkStatus {
  read -u 3 sts line
  expect=250
  if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    expect="${1}"
  fi
  if [ $sts -ne $expect ] ; then
    echo "Error: ${line}"
    exit
  fi
}

FromAddr="$(whoami)@${MyHost}"
ToAddr="admin@SomeDomain.com"
Subject="Status Alert"
Message='Msg: hello bozo!!'

# Brilliant!!
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${MailHost}/${MailPort} ; checkStatus 220

echo "HELO ${MyHost}" >&3 ; checkStatus
echo "MAIL FROM: ${FromAddr}" >&3 ; checkStatus
echo "RCPT TO: ${ToAddr}" >&3 ; checkStatus
echo "DATA" >&3 ; checkStatus 354
echo "Subject: ${Subject}" >&3

# Insert one blank line here to let the relay know you are done sending headers
# Otherwise a colon ":" in the message text will result in no text being sent.
echo "" >&3

# Send the message text and close
echo "${Message}" >&3
echo "." >&3 ; checkStatus
```